# How do you 'pop' a UIWebVIew?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView which I load like this:

```
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

When I want to get rid of it, what do I code?

Thanks?

Comment: [webView removeFromSuperview];

Comment: "Pop" implies you've "push"ed it onto a UINavigationViewController stack. Is that the case? Because it changes the answer to your question.

Comment: Nope. Haven't programatically pushed anything. Was using 'pop' as an analogy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[webView removeFromSuperview]
```

If you are completely finished with the webView, then release it afterwards

```
[webView release]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem does not have anything to do with the `UIWebView` itself. Perhaps you just want to know how to empty the `UIWebView`. I tested this:

```
[webview loadHTMLString:nil baseURL:nil];
```

Cheers,
Sascha